# I'm working on a Flask web application and trying to use jsonify to dynamically update an HTML table with messages and links

Tags: javascript, python, html

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a Flask application where I'm trying to dynamically update an HTML table based on JSON responses from a Flask route. I'm facing issues with updating the message and link in the table cells dynamically.

Here's a simplified version of my Flask route:

```
@app.route('/update_page', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def update_page():
    objects = Object.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).order_by(Object.time, Object.name).all()
    current_time = datetime.now()

    object_info = []

    for obj in objects:
        info = {'id': obj.id, 'name': obj.name, 'time': obj.time, 'message': '', 'link': ''}

        obj_time = datetime.strptime(obj.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        interval_minutes = int(2) * 60
        new_time = obj_time + timedelta(minutes=interval_minutes)

        if current_time < obj_time:
            info['message'] = 'Ai luat pastila'
            info['link'] = url_for('confirm_approved', object_id=obj.id, object_instructions=obj.instructions, object_dosage=obj.dosage)
        if obj_time < current_time < new_time:
            info['message'] = 'Trebuie să iei pastila'
            info['link'] = url_for('confirm_approved', object_id=obj.id, object_instructions=obj.instructions, object_dosage=obj.dosage)
        if current_time > new_time:
            info['message'] = 'Ai uitat să iei pastila'
            info['link'] = url_for('confirm_forget', object_id=obj.id, object_instructions=obj.instructions, object_dosage=obj.dosage)

        object_info.append(info)

    response = {"current_time": current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'), "object_info": object_info}

    return jsonify(response)
```

I'm using jQuery to make an AJAX call to this route and update the HTML dynamically. However, it seems like the message and link are not updating as expected.

Additionally, I have the following HTML code:

```
html
<!-- Relevant part of HTML code -->
<script>
        function updatePage() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/update_page',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#current_time').text(data.current_time);
    
                    $.each(data.object_info, function (index, obj) {
                        var confirmationLink = $('#confirmation_link_' + obj.id);
                        var linkPlaceholder = $('#confirmation_link_placeholder_' + obj.id);

                        if (obj.link) {
                            confirmationLink.attr('href', obj.link);
                            confirmationLink.text('Confirma');  // Update the content inside the link
                            linkPlaceholder.hide();
                            confirmationLink.show();
                        } else {
                            linkPlaceholder.show();
                            confirmationLink.hide();
                        }
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {
                    // Schedule the next update after 1 second
                    setTimeout(updatePage, 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    
        // Start updating the page when the document is ready
        $(document).ready(function () {
            updatePage();
        });
    </script>
<span id="confirmation_message_{{ obj.id }}">
    {% if obj.link %}
        <a href="{{ obj.link }}" id="confirmation_link_{{ obj.id }}">Confirma</a>
    {% else %}
        <span id="confirmation_link_placeholder_{{ obj.id }}">Link not available</span>
    {% endif %}
</span>
```

I suspect there might be an issue with my Python code or the way I'm updating the HTML. Can someone help me identify the problem and suggest a solution? Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!